# How do I get objects that I set in my NSMutableDictionary and make a touch interface?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying to make grid with touch capabilities using a `NSMutableDictionary`. I created a coordinate grid (`_coordinateRecords` being my dictionary) using this in the viewDidLoad function of the view controller:

```
[self _loopOnCellWithIterator: (^(int iLooper, int jLooper)
{
    int cellWidth = 10;
    int space = 1;

    [_coordinateRecords setObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: iLooper inSection: jLooper] forKey: [NSValue valueWithPointer: redCell]];

    redCell = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(iLooper * (cellWidth + space) + 24.25,
                                                         jLooper * (cellWidth + space) + 110,
                                                         cellWidth, cellWidth)] init];
    _cells[iLooper][jLooper] = redCell;

    [redCell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];

    [[self view] addSubview: redCell];
})];
```

using this block:

```
- (void)_loopOnCellWithIterator: (void(^)(int iLooper, int jLooper))iterator
{
    for (int iLooper = 0; iLooper < kCellSize; iLooper++)
    {
        for (int jLooper = 0; jLooper < kCellSize; jLooper++)
        {
            iterator(iLooper, jLooper);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I was wondering how I can call upon the objects in the dictionary that I set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but two things may help:

- You access the values in a dictionary using keys. The method `-objectForKey:` takes a key and returns the associated object. You're expected to know what the keys are, but there's also a method that provides an array containing all the keys.
- If you're having a hard time mapping from grid coordinates to dictionary keys, perhaps you're using the wrong data structure. An array may be more suitable since its easy to convert from coordinates to indices.